# Trigger event on selection of second box, Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 2 boxes the first you select parent, second you select the child of a selected parent.

How do I run the function bellow after the second selection ?

**angular function**

```
$scope.myFunc = function() {
            var jsonItem = JSON.parse($scope.formData.formatType.id);
            sessionStorage.setItem('format', jsonItem);
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="formData.ProductType.name" ng-change="productTypeChange()" ng-options="product.name as product.name for product in productsandformats">
    <option value="">- Please Choose -</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="formData.formatType" ng-options="format.Fname for format in formats.format" ng-if="formData.ProductType.name">
    <option value="">- Please Choose -</option>
</select>
```

Comment: accept answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: sorry I thought I had already mybad

Comment: Its fine. Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-change`

```
    <select ng-model="formData.formatType"
            ng-options="format.Fname for format in formats.format"
            ng-if="formData.ProductType.name" ng-change="myFunc()">
        <option value="">- Please Choose -</option>
    </select>`
```